# Renew StableIdKeyProvider cache and RecyclerView/SelectionTracker crash on new selection after item removed

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Preparation:

`RecyclerView` with `RecyclerView.Adapter` binded to SQLite `Cursor` (via `ContentProvider` && Loader). `RecyclerView` and `RecyclerView.Adapter` linked with `SelectionTracker` as [design suggests](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#select).
`SelectionTracker` builded with `StableIdKeyProvider`.

On first step - delete an item:

1. Select `RecyclerViews`'s an item with a long press (cheers to `SelectionTracker`'s `SelectionObserver`), draw Action Bar Context Menu, fire
   the delete action, do the SQL deletion task.
2. After SQL deletion ends, do the Cursor Loader renewal with
   `restartLoader` call.
3. `onLoadFinished` fired, new `Cursor` obtained, on
   `RecyclerView.Adapter` method `notifyDataSetChanged` called.
4. `RecyclerView.Adapter` redraw `RecyclerView` content, and all is looks
   good.

On second step - do the selection of some other item. Crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at androidx.core.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:38)
    at androidx.recyclerview.selection.DefaultSelectionTracker.anchorRange(DefaultSelectionTracker.java:269)
    at androidx.recyclerview.selection.MotionInputHandler.selectItem(MotionInputHandler.java:60)
    at androidx.recyclerview.selection.TouchInputHandler.onLongPress(TouchInputHandler.java:132)
    at androidx.recyclerview.selection.GestureRouter.onLongPress(GestureRouter.java:96)
    at android.view.GestureDetector.dispatchLongPress(GestureDetector.java:779)
    at android.view.GestureDetector.access$200(GestureDetector.java:40)
    at android.view.GestureDetector$GestureHandler.handleMessage(GestureDetector.java:293)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

What I see on first step while deletion item in progress.
While `StableIdKeyProvider` do internal job with `onDetached` `ViewHolder` item, it don't see previously assigned `ViewHolder`'s position within an Adapter:

```
   void onDetached(@NonNull View view) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = mRecyclerView.findContainingViewHolder(view);
        int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
        long id = holder.getItemId();
        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION && id != RecyclerView.NO_ID) {
```

`int position` here is `RecyclerView.NO_POSITION`

Thats why the RecyclerView crashes after - `StableIdKeyProvider`'s cache contains old snapshot of ID's without deletion affected.

The question is - WHY? and HOW to renew the cache of `StableIdKeyProvider`?

Another note:
While I read the `RecyclerView` code, I see this comment:

> ```
>      * Note that if you've called {@link RecyclerView.Adapter#notifyDataSetChanged()}, until the
>      * next layout pass, the return value of this method will be {#NO_POSITION}.
> ```

I am not understood what exactly mean this words. Perhaps I faced with described situation - `notifyDataSetChanged` called in not appropriate time? Or I need to call it twice?

PS.
Sorry for about literary description, there is a lot of complexity code

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am ended up to play with `StableIdKeyProvider` and switch to plain my own implementation of ItemKeyProvider:

```
new ItemKeyProvider<Long>(ItemKeyProvider.SCOPE_MAPPED) {
                    @Override
                    public Long getKey(int position) {
                        return adapter.getItemId(position);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getPosition(@NonNull Long key) {
                        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = recyclerList.findViewHolderForItemId(key);
                        return viewHolder == null ? RecyclerView.NO_POSITION : viewHolder.getLayoutPosition();
                    }
                }
```

Crash is gone, `RecyclerView`'s navigation/selection/modification looks OK.
What about `StableIdKeyProvider` ?.. Hmm, may be it is not designed to work with mutable content of `RecyclerView`.

**Update 2021-12-03**

Last week I got a new round with fighting on RecycleView.
As mentioned on the question - exactly problem is the CACHE of `StableIdKeyProvider`. And switch to `ItemKeyProvider` is the workaround.
As code of `StableIdKeyProvider` explains, chache tied to the window's evens: attach and detach. So, and the comment which I am quoted above - is the exactly pointed to the problem: when new `Cursor` arrives - reattaching `Cursor` to the `Adapter` and notifying - requires to fire at right time. "Right time" - is enqueue this job in layout-message-thread. In this way `RecyclerView` and underlying "toolbox" can correct perform an update itself. For doing so, just wrap providing a new `Cursor` inside the post runnable method. The code:

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    recycler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            adapter.swapCursor(data);
        }
    });
...
```

Comment: This was also happening to me on a RecyclerView with a SelectionTracker. This solution of replacing Google's StableIdKeyProvider with a custom ItemKeyProvider fixed a crash which was only happening on API < 24. Thank you!

Comment: Anybody knows, why this actually helps? :(

Comment: I've also encountered the same issue and it also left me wondering that maybe Google's `StableIdKeyProvider` is not suitable for RecyclerViews with mutable content... Thanks for the confirmation. In my case I'm wondering if maybe it is a mismatch of expectations given that I'm using a `SortedList` in my adapter. Maybe it issues updates in a different order than the one expected by the `StableIdKeyProvider`.

Answer (score 4):

My problem was solved by setting `setHasStableIds(true)` in Recycle view adapter and overriding `getItemId`, It seems that Tracker require both `setHasStableIds(true)` and overrinding`getItemId` in adapter I got this error after setting stable Ids true without overriding getItemId

```
 init {
    setHasStableIds(true)
}
override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = position
```

Comment: As described in the main question, Adapter linked within Sqlite as datasource. Overriding the `getItemId` is the only way to take a mapping between UI and data. So, modern RecyclerView has a lot of checks with raise of different exceptions on check fail. May be your behaviour is an effect from other check-fail-exception use case

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same problem and after a long search I have found the answer:
You just need to override the method in your Recycler Adapter view.

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with the StableIdKeyProvider. Writing a custom implementation of ItemKeyProvider seems to do the trick.  Here's a basic Kotlin implementation you can use when building a selection tracker for a RecyclerView:

```
class RecyclerViewIdKeyProvider(private val recyclerView: RecyclerView)
    : ItemKeyProvider<Long>(ItemKeyProvider.SCOPE_MAPPED) {

    override fun getKey(position: Int): Long? {
        return recyclerView.adapter?.getItemId(position)
                ?: throw IllegalStateException("RecyclerView adapter is not set!")
    }

    override fun getPosition(key: Long): Int {
        val viewHolder = recyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(key)
        return viewHolder?.layoutPosition ?: RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem is related to the initialization of `ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails` in `ViewHolder`. As it turned out, `getAdapterPosition()` may return the wrong position during `ViewHolder` binding. The solution is to call `getAdapterPosition()` at the time call `getItemDetails()` in `ItemDetailsLookup`.

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved by keeping the initialization and setting selectiontracker to the adapter at the very end.

```
    capturedThumbnailListAdapter = new CapturedThumbnailListAdapter(this);
    capturedThumbnailListAdapter.setCapturedThumbnailList(capturedThumbnailList);
    viewBinding.capturedImagesRv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
    viewBinding.capturedImagesRv.setAdapter(capturedThumbnailListAdapter);

    SelectionTracker<Long> tracker = new SelectionTracker.Builder<Long>("thumb_selection",
            viewBinding.capturedImagesRv, new StableIdKeyProvider(viewBinding.capturedImagesRv),
            new CapturedThumbnailListAdapter.ItemLookUp(viewBinding.capturedImagesRv),
            StorageStrategy.createLongStorage())
            .withSelectionPredicate(SelectionPredicates.createSelectAnything())
            .build();
    capturedThumbnailListAdapter.setSelectionTracker(tracker);
```